# Using JQ - Join 2 json files which do not have the same structure but with a common key

Tags: jq

I have 2 files that I would like to join based a common key.

The first file is an array with:

```
{"_time": "2022-02-20T23","csp_name": "1","tool_bf_id": "1234", "dvc_ssr": "aa-1111"}
{"_time": "2022-02-20T23","csp_name": "2","tool_bf_id": "4567", "dvc_ssr": "aa-2222"}
{"_time": "2022-02-20T23","csp_name": "3","tool_bf_id": "1357", "dvc_ssr": "null"}
{"_time": "2022-02-20T23","csp_name": "4","tool_bf_id": "2468", "dvc_ssr": "aa-1111"}
{"_time": "2022-02-20T23","csp_name": "5","tool_bf_id": "1246", "dvc_ssr": "null"}
```

The second file is also an array, a complete list of all the different "dvc_ssr" with:

```
{"host": "hostId1","dvc_ssr": "aa-1111"}
{"host": "hostId2","dvc_ssr": "aa-2222"}
```

I am trying to join both files by adding information from the second file into the first one using the dvc_ssr key value.

I am expecting something like this:

```
{"_time": "2022-02-20T23","csp_name": "1","tool_bf_id": "1234", "dvc_ssr": "aa-1111","host": "hostId1"}
{"_time": "2022-02-20T23","csp_name": "2",,"tool_bf_id": "4567", "dvc_ssr": "aa-2222","host": "hostId2"}
{"_time": "2022-02-20T23","csp_name": "3","tool_bf_id": "1357", "dvc_ssr": "null"}
{"_time": "2022-02-20T23","csp_name": "4","tool_bf_id": "2468", "dvc_ssr": "aa-1111","host": "hostId1"}
{"_time": "2022-02-20T23","csp_name": "5","tool_bf_id": "1246", "dvc_ssr": "null"}
```

After some research I found ideas using flatten/group_by/add ..

`flatten | group_by(.dvc_ssr) | map(reduce .[] as $x ({}; . * $x))`

or

`[.[1] + . [0] | group_by(.dvc_ssr) []  | add]`

But this is not working out.
The issue is by grouping them, I am grouping the "null" and also those which have the same "dvc_ssr". At then end I am losing some records.

I was able to join the files with jq -s (--slurp) and try to group array

`jq -s '[.[0] + .[1] | group_by(.dvc_ssr) []]' file1.json file2.json`

and I can remove then the not used record from the second file, by using:
 `|map(select(if ._time!=null then . else empty end))| .[]`

The idea is really to do a JOIN like in SQL where "dvc_ssr" are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using all parameters of `JOIN`, you'd do

```sh
jq --slurpfile fst first.json --slurpfile snd second.json -nc '
  JOIN(INDEX($snd[]; .dvc_ssr); $fst[]; .dvc_ssr; add)
'
```

```json
{"_time":"2022-02-20T23","csp_name":"1","tool_bf_id":"1234","dvc_ssr":"aa-1111","host":"hostId1"}
{"_time":"2022-02-20T23","csp_name":"2","tool_bf_id":"4567","dvc_ssr":"aa-2222","host":"hostId2"}
{"_time":"2022-02-20T23","csp_name":"3","tool_bf_id":"1357","dvc_ssr":"null"}
{"_time":"2022-02-20T23","csp_name":"4","tool_bf_id":"2468","dvc_ssr":"aa-1111","host":"hostId1"}
{"_time":"2022-02-20T23","csp_name":"5","tool_bf_id":"1246","dvc_ssr":"null"}
```

Depending on your application context, you could probably cut off some of them. For instance, JOIN with just two parameters accepts the stream as input and lets you process the joining outside of `JOIN`.

Same example (notice `-s` instead of `-n`, and `JOIN(…)[]` instead of `JOIN(…)`):

```sh
jq --slurpfile snd second.json -sc '
  JOIN(INDEX($snd[]; .dvc_ssr); .dvc_ssr)[] | add
' first.json
```