# Using JQ - Join records after been split and modified

Tags: jq

I have an array where some records need to be duplicated. The id value might be a join of 2 string by ";", as below

`{"_time": "2022-02-20T23","csp_name": "1","tool_bf_id": "1234", "id":"aa-1111;aa-2222"}`

or id value is null or only 1 ref:

```
{"_time": "2022-02-20T23","csp_name": "3","tool_bf_id": "1357", "dvc_ssr": "null"}
{"_time": "2022-02-20T23","csp_name": "4","tool_bf_id": "2468", "dvc_ssr": "aa-3333"}
```

I am able to duplicate this record and get the following:

```
{"_time": "2022-02-20T23","csp_name": "1","tool_bf_id": "1234", "dvc_ssr": "aa-1111","id":"aa-1111;aa-2222"},
{"_time": "2022-02-20T23","csp_name": "1","tool_bf_id": "1234", "dvc_ssr": "aa-2222","id":"aa-1111;aa-2222"}
```

Thanks to another post: [Join 2 files using a common key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71248425/using-jq-join-2-json-files-which-do-not-have-the-same-structure-but-with-a-com/71249114#71249114)

I modify my records by joining data from another file:

```
{"_time":"2022-02-20T23","csp_name":"1","tool_bf_id":"1234","id":"aa-1111;aa-2222", "dvc_ssr":"aa-1111","host":"hostId1"}
,{"_time":"2022-02-20T23","csp_name":"1","tool_bf_id":"1234","id":"aa-1111;aa-2222","dvc_ssr":"aa-2222","host":"hostId2"}
```

Now I need to merge the records back and join the value from the new added fields (which are around 10)

`{"_time": "2022-02-20T23","csp_name": "1","tool_bf_id": "1234", "id":"aa-1111;aa-2222", "host": "hostId1;hostId2"}`

Comment: You keep calling stream arrays, even though that's something completely differnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hosts.jsonl`:

```json
{ "host": "hostId1", "dvc_ssr": "aa-1111" }
{ "host": "hostId2", "dvc_ssr": "aa-2222" }
{ "host": "hostId3", "dvc_ssr": "aa-3333" }
```

`records.jsonl`:

```json
{ "_time": "2022-02-20T23", "csp_name": "1", "tool_bf_id": "1234", "id":"aa-1111;aa-2222" }
{ "_time": "2022-02-20T23", "csp_name": "3", "tool_bf_id": "1357", "dvc_ssr": "null" }
{ "_time": "2022-02-20T23", "csp_name": "4", "tool_bf_id": "2468", "dvc_ssr": "aa-3333" }
```

```sh
jq -n --slurpfile hosts hosts.jsonl '
   INDEX( $hosts[]; .dvc_ssr ) as $host_lkup |

   inputs |
   .host =
      if has("dvc_ssr") then
         $host_lkup[.dvc_ssr].host
      elif has("id") then
         .id / ";" | map( $host_lkup[.].host ) | join(";")
      else
         null
      end
' records.jsonl
```

Output:

```json
{
  "_time": "2022-02-20T23",
  "csp_name": "1",
  "tool_bf_id": "1234",
  "id": "aa-1111;aa-2222",
  "host": "hostId1;hostId2"
}
{
  "_time": "2022-02-20T23",
  "csp_name": "3",
  "tool_bf_id": "1357",
  "dvc_ssr": "null",
  "host": null
}
{
  "_time": "2022-02-20T23",
  "csp_name": "4",
  "tool_bf_id": "2468",
  "dvc_ssr": "aa-3333",
  "host": "hostId3"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/XMVpNK74vX) on jqplay

Comment: It's taking forever to go through the files. I also need to add more fields from the hosts file. `.email = if has("dvc_ssr") then .dvc_ssr / ";" | map( $host_lkup[.].applicationOwnerEmail ) | join(";") else empty end`

Comment: I don't get what this is doing : `.dvc_ssr / ";"`

Comment: So read the docs or try it

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and made some mod. it's working perfectly at small scale. But when going over it with real data it's taking forever. .dvc_ssr / ";" <=> .dvc_ssr | contains(";") ???